# What is the best way to modify the font family of CanvasRenderingContext2D.font without affecting anything else?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm currently creating a game using Javascript and HTML canvas.

I faced a problem when I was creating a function to modify the font family of `CanvasRenderingContext2D.font`, without changing anything else. My function looks like this.

```
function font(ctx, fontName='sans-serif') {
    /* 
    consider cases where ctx.font is in form:
        '10px Arial', '10px 10px', '10px "Arial Arial"', '10px' 
    */

    ctx.font = ctx.font.split('px')[0] + 'px ' + fontName;
    return ctx.font; // ignore this part
}
```

I want to make this function applicable to any kind of situation.

The problem is, I'm not confident that this function can deal with every situation.

**And my question is this:** Are there any chance where `CanvasRenderingContext2D.font` will not take the form `'... [font size]px [font family]'`? Because otherwise, my function **will** definitely break (for instance, if it can be in the form `'... [font size]px [font family] ...'`, the part after font family will completely be removed)

And this is extra, but does anyone know what is the best way to set the font family of`CanvasRenderingContext2D.font` without effecting anything else? I tried searching but did not manage to get to an answer. Thank you :)

(P.S. I'm pretty sure SOF is the right place to post this, and not code review, sorry if I'm mistaken!)

Comment: I'd store the font's size in pixels and name in separate variables; change those as necessary, then combine them into the CSS string when setting .font. Code should never rely on awkward strings to store values, just because they happen to be used in CSS or HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are there any chance where CanvasRenderingContext2D.font will not take the form '... [font size]px [font family]'?

Yes, you can very well have the font size set to an other value than `px`:

```js
const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.font = "1cm sans-serif";
console.log( ctx.font );
```

For parsing a `font` shorthand property, the best is probably the CSSOM.

You could use a dummy HTML element, set its `.style.font` to the ctx's `font` value, then control better each component:

```js
const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.font = "bold 1em sans-serif";

function editFontFamily( short, new_value ) {
  const dummy_el = document.createElement('i');
  const style = dummy_el.style; 
  style.font = short;
  style.fontFamily = new_value;
  const new_short = [ "font-style", "font-variant", "font-weight", "font-stretch", "font-size", "font-family" ]
    .map( (long) => style[ long ] );
  return new_short.join( " " );
}

ctx.font = editFontFamily( ctx.font, "myOwnFontFamily" );
console.log( ctx.font );
```

Now, if you are entirely responsible of what controls your context (and you should be), it would be a lot better to simply store each components in their own variables and update these as you need.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Looks tremendously safer and cleaner. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: I just realised chrome converts a lot of things to `px` automatically. `em`, `cm`,  where some other browsers don't. Didn't know that til now.

Comment: Yes, and I just learned it's [actually per specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#dom-context-2d-font).